# UITableView with max unsigned integer number of rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, fibonacci

Trying to create a `UITableView` in Swift that displays `Uint.max` number of rows/cells with Fibonacci numbers from 1 to N, where N is the max for the native unsigned integer.

When you print `UInt.max`, it shows `18446744073709551615`. However, the UITableView doesn't support an index that large and operators such as `<` and `-` can't be applied to operands of type `Int` and `UInt` being used inside the Fibonacci function.

How can `Uint`s be used with UITableViews to show the Fibonacci sequence up to `UInt.max`?

Comment: A table view with 18446744073709551615 rows? Are you serious? How long does it take to scroll to the bottom?

Comment: I am curious: How would you compute the 18446744073709551615'th Fibonacci number? It is quite large.

Comment: @MartinR If you could scroll 1000 rows per second (not likely), it would take 584.5 million years to scroll to the bottom of the table view containing 1.844e19 rows. Better get started.

Comment: Of course. But the question is asking how one can use UInts to work with tableviews to display the sequence. Obviously, the problem is figuring out a way to simulate this and reuse the cells, not actually keep UInt.max cells...

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your cells into several table view sections (2 should be enough)